# How to add multiple arguments into XPath and replace %s to param

Tags: java, string, selenium, xpath, string-formatting

I have a string (e.g):

```
xpath = //tagname[text()='param1']/tagname[text()='param2']/tagname[text()='param3']
```

var param can increase from 1 => n (param1, param2, param3 .... paramN)

I want to build a function to add multiple arguments into xpath and I have to use String format in Java to put multiple value into xpath and do not know how to replace param to %s and use String format put multiple arguments.

> How can i build a function with replace param to %s?

Thank you so much.

Comment: `String.format("Hello %s the %s %s", "from", "other", "side");`

Comment: String name="sonoo";  String sf1=String.format("name is %s",name);   //name is sonoo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose xpath is "//tagname[text()='param']/tagname[text()='param']/tagname[text()='param']" and param is pattern that need to be replaced.

```
public static String replaceValue(String xpath , String...params){
    for(String replacement : params){
        xpath = xpath.replaceFirst("param",replacement);
    }
    return xpath;
}
```

you also can use a regex pattern instead of 'param' keyword in xpath.

Comment: hi @Tanuj Vishnoi, thank you for suggestion.
I was use replaceAll and regex for case change paramN to %s, my code:
https://repl.it/repls/DramaticOvercookedActivemovie

But, i have facing with String format because i can not change value after i handle step above.

Comment: I would need a peace of code to check the exact issue. but i did make change in the code repl.it/repls/DramaticOvercookedActivemovie

Comment: hi "Tanuj Vishnoi, what about if I use String format to put value into %s?

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me @Tanuj Vishnoi

Answer (score 1):

You can different variables to be replaced within the [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  String str1 = "stringA";
  String str2 = "stringB";
  String str3 = "stringC";
  System.out.println("//tagname[text()='" +str1+ "']/tagname[text()='" +str2+ "']/tagname[text()='" +str3+ "']");
  ```
- Console output:

  ```
  //tagname[text()='stringA']/tagname[text()='stringB']/tagname[text()='stringC']
  ```

Comment: If i have more 10 param as 'param1' 'pram2' 'param3' 'pram4' 'pram5' 'param6 'param7' 'param8" 'param9' 'param10' 'param11'...... 'param100' then how do i handle it?

Comment: @MichealNguyen There are n number of other different ways. I simply answered the most easiest way. The question is how differently do you want to handle it? Can you raise anew question with your new requirement please?

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB.: Thank you very much for your answers. But I have to facing about how to change paramN => %s and how do you use String Format to change value in order.
I have a case for change paramN => %s but i do not know how to use String Format to change value order. Please access my link https://repl.it/repls/DramaticOvercookedActivemovie